# Customs/Habits around having a second child?

Tags: commentaries, pregnancy-birth, mesorah-tradition

Besides the brit milah ceremony, pidyon haben/habat (redemption of the firstborn) or kidush peter rechem (sanctification of the womb's opening) or seder kidushat chaye hamishpacha, (ceremony of consecration to family life) is there a dedication ceremony for second children or for those following the first one’s? And are there other custums for introducing a child to or welcoming a child into a congregation?

Comment: Are you asking for customs specific to a second or subsequent child, which are not performed for a firstborn?

Comment: “Besides Pidyon HaBen” which doesn’t apply to a secondborn anyway?

Comment: Some people have a custom of making a kiddush celebration in honor of the birth of a girl.

Comment: And a shalom zachar on the Friday night following the birth of a boy

Comment: You may find this interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wimpel and https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/683154/jewish/Bringing-Back-the-Wimpel.htm

Comment: What is "seder kidushat chaye hamishpacha" and where does it come from?